# Converting date string to date object in BSD MacOSX

Tags: bash, macos, date, sh

In mac osx bsd, `date -vmon` will convert the current date to Monday's date and `date +%w` displays day of week.

Say, I have input date 9/14/16 in the format mm/dd/yy. How can I convert this string pattern to a date object so that I could perform date functions like `-vmon` and `+%w` on it.

I tried the following: `startDate=$(date -jf "%m/%d/%y" "9/14/16")` and then tried to perform `$startDate +"%w"` but it doesn't work. I doubt that the startDate is not date and actually String.

How can I convert the string to date so that I perform date manipulation on it?

Edit: The requirement for doing this is: Say an input date is given. Then corresponding to that date, I want to get the beginning and ending working dates of the week i.e Monday's date and Friday's date. Then I want to get next week's Monday's date and Friday's date. How can I do this?

Comment: You can't; there are no date objects, just strings written by `date` to standard output.

Comment: Thanks @chepner. I just edited my post explaining my requirement in detail.

Comment: You probably need a more powerful language than bash, for example `python`.  The GNU version of `awk` (`gawk`) has some datetime functions, but I think they would be tricky to do what you need.

Comment: Thank you @cdarke. I'll try my hand at python then. If you know of way to do in python, please share.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `date` twice, once to convert from the string input to an 'epoch time' (the number of seconds since The Epoch — aka 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +00:00), and once to convert an epoch time to an output format of your choosing:

```
rdate="9/14/16"
epoch_time=$(date -j -f '%m/%d/%y' "$rdate" +'%s')
date -j -vmon -r "$epoch_time"
date -j -vfri -r "$epoch_time" +'%w'
```

That gave me the output:

```
Mon Sep 12 10:14:44 PDT 2016
5
```

Note that Friday is day 5 of the week, so the output is correct.  The use of `%w` when you specify `-v`*`dow`* seems a little moot; you know that the output will be 5.  But you can use any other format characters that you need too.

Note that the time portion is defaulted to the current time.  You could add `00:00:00` to the converted date and `%H:%M:%S` to the conversion format (`-f` argument) to work with midnight, etc.

You can combine it into one command line:

```
$ date -j -vmon -r $(date -j -f '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S' "$rdate 00:00:00"  +'%s') +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %w %s'
2016-09-12 00:00:00 1 1473663600
$
```

The last example on the man page for `date` on Mac OS X mentions the `%s` format specifier, which is the key to getting this to work.  Well, that and using `date` twice.

Note that the man page gives synopses:

```
 date [-ju] [-r seconds] [-v [+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... [+output_fmt]
 date [-jnu] [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]
 date [-jnu] -f input_fmt new_date [+output_fmt]
 date [-d dst] [-t minutes_west]
```

The 'usage' message is less helpful:

```
usage: date [-jnu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
```

The usage message doesn't show that you can't use `-f` with `-r` or `-v`, whereas the manual is clear that you cannot.

Tested: Mac OS X 10.11.6 El Capitan

Comment: The usage message could be clearer, but I think it is implying that there are two non-overlapping ways to call `date`: the first line and the second line. It would be immensely clearer if the second line started with `date` as well, so that it would be harder to confuse the second line with a continuation of the first.

Comment: @chepner: Ah, …, yes.  Repeating the command name would make it clearer, but you are correct.

Comment: Excellent answer. Thanks a ton for the detailed clarification. Yes, the last example in `man date` mentions `%s` which I was missing. 

Apologies for accepting this answer so late. I got pulled into another work and couldn't try this out until today.